# Android React Native Statusbar for modal

Tags: android, react-native, statusbar

```
<Modal
 visible={this.props.show}
 onRequestClose={this.closeModal}
 onShow={this.onModalShow}
 animationType='slide'
 translucentStatusBar={true}
>
```

is there a way for modal statusbar to achieve something like this?

```
<StatusBar
 backgroundColor="Pink"
/>
```

on modal it seems to be just have 50% transparency for statusbar, unlike statusbar on normal screen, and it seems statusbar tag doesn't work for modal as well.

I found that translucentstatusbar from [Here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/7157) please help me....